# Two-way mutable pointer relationship with trait DerefMut in a container-element setup?

Tags: rust, mutable, dereference

I am trying to implement something which Rust's ownership rules almost seem designed to make impossible. But it's very simple: I want a framework containing a hashmap where the values are a class, `TextDocument`, which has a reference to the framework.

That itself is fairly tricky to do, but with `RefCell<Weak<Framework<'a>>>,` it is possible.

However, I also want to be able to reach out from inside methods of the `TextDocument` to modify things in the framework!

MRE:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub fn str_type_of<T>(_: &T) -> &str {
    std::any::type_name::<T>()
}

fn main() {
    let mut framework = Framework::new();
    framework.populate_map();
    println!("framework.map {:?}", framework.map);

    // now set up the pointer to the framework for the TextDocuments
    let rc = Rc::new(framework);
    
    for (key, td) in rc.map.iter(){
    
        *td.framework.borrow_mut() = Rc::downgrade(&rc);
        println!("key {} td {:?}", key, td );
    
        // at this point obtaining a reference to Framework using td.framework is possible:
        let weak_ref_to_framework = &*td.framework.borrow();
        let inner_ref_to_framework = weak_ref_to_framework.upgrade().unwrap();
        println!("inner_ref_to_framework {:?} type {}", inner_ref_to_framework, str_type_of(&inner_ref_to_framework));
    
        // ... but it is impossible using an Rc<Framework> to alter anything in the Framework
        // BAD: inner_ref_to_framework.name = "bumblebee".to_string();
        // error: "trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, 
        // but it is not implemented for `Rc<Framework<'_>>`"
    }
    
    // we have also obviously lost the ability to change anything in the Framework's Rc
    // BAD: rc.name = "bubbles".to_string();
    
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TextDocument {
    framework: RefCell<Weak<Framework>>,
    i: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Framework {
    map: HashMap<String, TextDocument>,
    name: String,
}

impl Framework {
    fn new() -> Framework {
        Framework {
            map: HashMap::new(),
            name: "my framework".to_string(),
        }
    }   
    
    fn populate_map(&mut self){
        for i in 0..5 {
            let td = TextDocument{
                framework: RefCell::new(Weak::new()),
                i,
            };
            self.map.insert(format!("document {i}"), td);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, I know that such a setup, whereby it would be possible to modify the framework's fields from within methods of a given `TextDocument`, would be safe. I accept to take responsibility for that guarantee.

Is there any way to do this in Rust?

NB I have been wrestling with this problem for some time, and implemented for example a workaround involving a third structure, with references going from the framework and from the `TextDocument`s, a `struct` `MapHolder`. But it's far from ideal, and I'd really like to find something simpler, presumably not involving `Rc` ... but something else.

Another workaround possibility which occurs is a `std::sync::mpsc::channel`: `TextDocument` transmits, `Framework` receives, and acts accordingly. But it seems crazy that I should be forced to go to such lengths to accomplish something so straightforward.

***Edit***
To answer ChrisB: no, there's a single framework. But the framework does various things such as keep track of how these documents have been processed. In a later stage of development the documents (text documents, such as MS Word .docx files in fact) will be parsed in parallel, and to keep track of the total number of words processed, for the purpose of sending inter-process messages to update a progress counter, an atomic variable has to be used, I think. In my workaround I used one or two `Arc`s which were then made fields of the `TextDocument` struct. Maybe this is the only acceptable Rust way ... but I simply can't understand why reaching out to the framework in this setup should be such a big deal. Is it not possible to stipulate that the `TextDocument`s will always have a shorter lifetime than that of the `Framework`?

The `TextDocument`s also have to be able to **detect** an **in-coming** inter-process message, i.e. ordering everything to cancel. This also involves `Arc`s within the `TextDocument` `struct`. The "natural" object to detect this seems to be the framework...

***Specifically what I want to improve***
To answer Chayim Friedman's question: I want methods of `TextDocument` to be able to use a reference to change something in the framework, either directly change a property or to execute a `&mut self` method. My current understanding is that simply isn't going to be possible, but I'm a newb in Rust. Rather tortuous use of `Arc` fields in `TextDocument` may be the absolutely ONLY solution to what I'm trying to achieve, but I just want to be more certain of that, from you, the experts. Everything the compiler does makes sense and obeys the logic of safety. But conversely the requirement seems so simple. That's what I'm struggling with.
PS thanks for the headsup on `type_name_of_val`: 1.76, just upgraded! Also, yes, the lifetimes are redundant. They were put in due to compiler demands: not sure what's changed since. Will change MRE.

Comment: If you know the multiple keys upfront, then it sounds like you want something like [`get_many_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_many_mut). In `std` it is unable, however `std` is just a wrapper around the [`hashbrown` crate](https://crates.io/crates/hashbrown) where [`get_many_mut()`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/hashbrown/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_many_mut) is ready to be used

Comment: Whether that's _the_ solution is something entirely else. Usually when you run into cases where `Rc<RefCell<T>>` seems like the solution, then it's a lot of the times just a sign of poor design. Sometimes you can get rid of it, by inverting the relationship between some of the types

Comment: I think a bit more context would be useful here.
**Why** do you need to access the `Framework` from within the `TextDocument`?
I assume this is because you have multiple `Framework`s. So, what datastructure are the `Framework`s stored in? For example, depending on your usecase, you might be able to get away with storing all the frameworks in a `Vec`, and simply storing an index to the correct one inside the `TextDocument`.

Comment: As you said, cyclical, mutable references are the antithesis to Rust's ownership model.
If you **really** need this, and are happy to use `unsafe` as you say, the easiest solution might just be to use raw pointers. Just have to be careful about the order of destruction and thread safety.

Comment: Nit: The lifetime is completely redundant. Also, `type_name_of_val()` is stable now.

Comment: Specifically what do you want to improve in this example? The usage of `RefCell`? Of `Rc`? Of `Weak`? The possibility to forget to attach the framework `Weak`? Please elaborate.

Comment: Also importantly: do the `TextDocument`s need access to the map of `TextDocument`s?

Comment: You didn't answer my question: what do you want to improve in this example? In other words, why is this code using `Rc` and `Weak` not good enough for you? If you are seeking the "best", then I recommend you won't (be practical) and also this is off-topic here. If you have specific requirements, this is something we can work with.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Well, as I explained in the original question, I can reference the framework read-only from the TextDocument, but I want to be able to **mutate** it (the framework) as well, from inside a method of TextDocument. Is that not specific?

Comment: Now I see what you mean. But you can solve that by wrapping the framework's data in `Rc`, e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e7b2d71f8b491245627b061b1a5cd9c4. Is this your only problem?

Comment: OMG! You see, that's exactly what I meant by "from you, the experts"! I've been tearing my hair out about this for months, thinking that it was "just something no-one could do" and that I had to live with it. At the same time I wondered whether it was just my lack of expertise. Please add an answer so you get the bounty.

Comment: Before I add the answer, note this won't allow you to mutate the map, only the additional elements (although it can be made to allow mutating the map too). Is that enough for you?

Comment: I was precisely wondering that, perusing the code. For my specific requirement the map doesn't need to be mutable (from the TextDocuments) ... but if you can show how to do that without getting forbidden by the compiler, that would be doubly instructive, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `Framework` data in `RefCell`, e.g.:

```rust
use std::any::type_name_of_val;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

fn main() {
    let mut framework = Framework::new();
    framework.populate_map();
    println!("framework.map {:?}", framework.map);

    // now set up the pointer to the framework for the TextDocuments
    let rc = Rc::new(framework);

    for (key, td) in rc.map.iter() {
        *td.framework.borrow_mut() = Rc::downgrade(&rc);
        println!("key {} td {:?}", key, td);

        // at this point obtaining a reference to Framework using td.framework is possible:
        let weak_ref_to_framework = &*td.framework.borrow();
        let inner_ref_to_framework = weak_ref_to_framework.upgrade().unwrap();
        println!(
            "inner_ref_to_framework {:?} type {}",
            inner_ref_to_framework,
            type_name_of_val(&inner_ref_to_framework)
        );

        inner_ref_to_framework.data.borrow_mut().name = "bumblebee".to_string();
    }

    rc.data.borrow_mut().name = "bubbles".to_string();
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TextDocument {
    framework: RefCell<Weak<Framework>>,
    i: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Framework {
    map: HashMap<String, TextDocument>,
    data: RefCell<FrameworkData>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct FrameworkData {
    name: String,
}

impl Framework {
    fn new() -> Framework {
        Framework {
            map: HashMap::new(),
            data: RefCell::new(FrameworkData {
                name: "my framework".to_string(),
            }),
        }
    }

    fn populate_map(&mut self) {
        for i in 0..5 {
            let td = TextDocument {
                framework: RefCell::new(Weak::new()),
                i,
            };
            self.map.insert(format!("document {i}"), td);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ce8dc1e4b9e59dfd08b409fa01e32c45).

Note that this will not allow you to mutate the map from a document. This is because if we include the map in the `RefCell`, in order to get a component, we need to borrow it and then access its `Weak`, but we cannot borrow this `Weak`'s `RefCell` mutably in order to mutate the map because we're already borrowing the framework.

The solution (if needed) is to detach the processed document from the framework, for instance by wrapping documents in `Rc` (possibly with `RefCell`) and clone it, release the framework guard, then access the framework via the `Weak`, or by removing the document from the map, accessing its `Weak`, then inserting it again.

Also note that if all documents are known upfront [`Rc::new_cyclic()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.new_cyclic) can provide much friendlier experience:

```rust
use std::any::type_name_of_val;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

fn main() {
    let rc = Framework::new();
    println!("framework.map {:?}", rc.map);

    for (key, td) in rc.map.iter() {
        println!("key {} td {:?}", key, td);

        // at this point obtaining a reference to Framework using td.framework is possible:
        let inner_ref_to_framework = td.framework.upgrade().unwrap();
        println!(
            "inner_ref_to_framework {:?} type {}",
            inner_ref_to_framework,
            type_name_of_val(&inner_ref_to_framework)
        );

        inner_ref_to_framework.data.borrow_mut().name = "bumblebee".to_string();
    }

    rc.data.borrow_mut().name = "bubbles".to_string();
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TextDocument {
    framework: Weak<Framework>,
    i: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Framework {
    map: HashMap<String, TextDocument>,
    data: RefCell<FrameworkData>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct FrameworkData {
    name: String,
}

impl Framework {
    fn new() -> Rc<Framework> {
        Rc::new_cyclic(|this| Framework {
            map: (0..5)
                .map(|i| {
                    let td = TextDocument {
                        framework: Weak::clone(this),
                        i,
                    };
                    let key = format!("document {i}");
                    (key, td)
                })
                .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>(),
            data: RefCell::new(FrameworkData {
                name: "my framework".to_string(),
            }),
        })
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=22e275c481b48940386091b753f4c887).